# Unity UnityWebRequest Coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use UnityWebRequest within a Unity Coroutine and I tried this way but I don't get results:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class rest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Coroutine<T> StartCoroutine<T>(IEnumerator coroutine)
    {
        Coroutine<T> coroutineObj = new Coroutine<T>();
        coroutineObj.coroutine = base.StartCoroutine(coroutineObj.InternalRoutine(coroutine));
        return coroutineObj;
    }

    public class Coroutine<T>
    {
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                return returnVal;
            }
        }
        private T returnVal;
        private Exception e;
        public Coroutine coroutine;

        public IEnumerator InternalRoutine(IEnumerator coroutine)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!coroutine.MoveNext())
                    {
                        yield break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    this.e = e;
                    yield break;
                }
                object yielded = coroutine.Current;
                if (yielded != null && yielded.GetType() == typeof(T))
                {
                    returnVal = (T)yielded;
                    yield break;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return coroutine.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var routine = StartCoroutine<int>(TestNewRoutineGivesException());
        yield return routine.coroutine;
        try
        {
            Debug.Log(routine.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
            Debug.Break();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TestNewRoutineGivesException()
    {
        yield return null;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:3000/api/players");
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return www.Send();
        while (!www.downloadHandler.isDone) yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string results = www.downloadHandler.text;
            yield return results;
        }
    }
}
```

but if for example my TestNewRoutineGivesException looks like this, then it works

```
IEnumerator TestNewRoutineGivesException()
{
    yield return null;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    yield return new 100;
}
```

it will return "100"

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: try explicitly creating the `www.downloadHandler` after creating `www` object. I remember I had some problems with this as well. Try this: 

`www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();` before `yield return www.Send();`

Comment: and maybe, just in case, try waiting in coroutine with this: `while(!www.downloadHandler.isDone) yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the changes, but it still doesn't work. there's no error, the problem is it returns 0 instead of the actual output.

Comment: I think you can't return too many times from a coroutine.. it looks like it gets stuck after first `yield return www.Send();`

Comment: try debugging and see what's going on in `www` object after it receives the response

Comment: no you can return as many times as you want from coroutine. Oh crap, you are using your own custom coroutine which expects all the yielded objects to be of type `T` while `www.Send()` is independent from `T`. So I guess you have to use the standard coroutine :/

Comment: I was using that because I wanted to return data from my co-routine and that's the only way I found how to do it [here](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post83_coroutines-more-than-you-want-to-know)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: (as of late 2018) use [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) instead of `WWW` class

---

try this:

```
public class rest : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Coroutine routine = StartCoroutine(TestNewRoutineGivesException());
    }

    IEnumerator TestNewRoutineGivesException()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:3000/api/players");
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return www.Send();
        while (!www.downloadHandler.isDone)
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string results = www.downloadHandler.text;
            DoSomethingWithTheCoroutineResult(result);
        }

        yield break;
    }

    void DoSomethingWithTheCoroutineResult(string result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Successfully got the result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to do. No difference from doing it standard like https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html I wanted to have return data directly at hand, otherwise is way too messy. Thanks for trying though